# Azure Domain Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've set up an azure domain services in a vnet, and already have a Win10 VM there.  The DNS of the vnet was already updated successfully as well.

I would like to administer the domain with a specific account, "adadmin", which I created in my default Azure AD i.e. adadmin@azureaddefault.onmicrosoft.com. I added the account to the "AAD DC Administrators" group.  However, i am unable to use the account to join the machines to the managed AD domain.

My understanding that creating the account after activating the domain services should allow creation of the NTLM hashes so the accounts can be used to manage the domain resources. Anyone encountered this issue during domain provisioning?

Comment: can you ping that domain name in that VM?

Comment: yes I was able to ping the domain, and use the nslookup to lookup SOA records for the AAD DS.  The issue here is that i do not think the account sync happened between AAD and AAD DS.

Comment: Since, i have re-created the AAD DS and making sure that the name matches.  Then, change of password seems to fix the issue.  When I have some bandwidth, i'll try to re-create this in my company's msdn subscription scenario to validate that indeed customizing the name was preventing me from synchronizing the accounts.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved:)  I will update your solution to my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding that creating the account after activating the domain
>   services should allow creation of the NTLM hashes so the accounts can
>   be used to manage the domain resources.

You are right, we can use the members of the `AAD DC Administrators` group to add join machines to the managed domain, more information we can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-domain#administrative-tasks-you-can-perform-on-a-managed-domain)

After you add users to that group, we should wait about 5 mins, and **flush** this machine, then use this account to add this machine to AAD DS.

**Note**:
Close `system properties` and re-open it, then use this account to join domain.

More information about join a Windows Server VM to AAD DS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal).

---

**Update**:

As Roman said, **re-create** the AAD DS and **change** the password, fix this problem.

Comment: The issue that I found interesting is that my ADDS domain name was customized (i made it shorter during provisioning step).  I have changed the password of the existing Azure AD account in  AAD DC Administrators group and still was not able to perform ad join.  I ended up re-creating the entire domain with a matching domain name as Azure AD